# Changes to Gedit through gsettings seem to be ignored

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-20.04, gedit

I'm trying to use `gsettings` to change some of my Gedit settings (Ubuntu 20.04), but my changes seem to be ignored by Gedit. For example, when I change the tab width through

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor tabs-size 4
```

my new tab width does show up in

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep gedit
```

but when I open anything in Gedit, it's still using the default tab width of 8.

In this example case this isn't much of a problem, as I can change the tab width from the Gedit GUI as well, but other settings, such as right margin position, don't seem to be in the Gedit Preferences menu.

When I tried to `sudo` the `gsettings` command I got this error:

```
(process:4742): dconf-WARNING **: 08:03:40.804: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=0d66e8250a634e9d8ee4675ca3d977fa --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

So what would be the correct way to use gsettings here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after a good bit of additional searching I found this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/491217/how-change-gedit-preferences-in-xfce-xubuntu#491296

So apparently (at least part of) my problem is that I'm using the Xfce desktop (I'm usually working over a VNC connection). I'm not sure exactly why/how this causes Gedit to ignore settings changed through `gsettings`, but installing dconf-editor and changing Gedit's settings there did the trick for me.